# unrecognized selector sent to instance & Terminating app due to uncaught exception in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

unrecognized selector sent to instance & Terminating app due to uncaught exception in ios.unrecognized selector sent to instance & Terminating app due to uncaught exception in ios // Close UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[[I18n sharedInstance] cancelButton] style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(dismissSignatureView:)]; [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:closeButton]; [closeButton release];

```
   // Close
    UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[[I18n sharedInstance] cancelButton]
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                   target:self
                                                                   action:@selector(dismissSignatureView:)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:closeButton];
    [closeButton release];
    
    
    // Close Button
    UIBarButtonItem *eraseButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                   target:self
                                                              action:@selector(eraseSignature:)];
    
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:eraseButton];
    [eraseButton release];
    
    // Close and Save
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[[I18n sharedInstance] okButton]
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(dismissSignatureViewAndSelect:)];
    doneButton.tag = fieldTag;
  
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton];
    [doneButton release];
    
    [self.signatureSheet.navigationBarView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:closeButton, eraseButton, doneButton, nil]];
   
    [self.signatureSheet viewWillAppear:NO];
```

Comment: You're not using ARC?

Comment: Why are you releasing before using? And setting the left button twice will replace. So one button will be destroyed before you use it...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Close
    UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[[I18n sharedInstance] cancelButton]
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                   target:self
                                                                   action:@selector(dismissSignatureView:)];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:closeButton];



    // Close Button
    UIBarButtonItem *eraseButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear"
                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                   target:self
                                                              action:@selector(eraseSignature:)];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:eraseButton];


    // Close and Save
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[[I18n sharedInstance] okButton]
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(dismissSignatureViewAndSelect:)];
    doneButton.tag = fieldTag;

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton];


    [self.signatureSheet.navigationBarView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:closeButton, eraseButton, doneButton, nil]];

    [self.signatureSheet viewWillAppear:NO];
```